# How to react to CLKComplicationServerActiveComplicationsDidChangeNotification

Tags: swift, apple-watch, nsnotificationcenter, apple-watch-complication, clockkit

On the helpful question [Force reload watchOS 2 Complications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32575156/force-reload-watchos-2-complications) user @alexeyvmp mentions [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32575156/force-reload-watchos-2-complications#comment60319563_32595164) that you should add an observer for the `CLKComplicationServerActiveComplicationsDidChangeNotification` event.

What is a good place to create this observer, and what would it look like? Do I create it from my ComplicationDataSource, or in my InterfaceController? How do I make sure it's not recreated over and over?

I have tried to read up on how to create observers in `Swift` but I'm having a hard time figuring out where to put it. I currently have

```
let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
let mainQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()

_ = notificationCenter.addObserverForName(CLKComplicationServerActiveComplicationsDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: mainQueue) { _ in
    print("active complications changed. refresh!")
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should place the observer in *InterfaceController*:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver( self,
        selector: #selector(InterfaceController.CLKComplicationServerActiveComplicationsDidChangeNotification(_:)),
        name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "CLKComplicationServerActiveComplicationsDidChangeNotification"), object: nil )
```

So you will know in *InterfaceController* when the complication changed.