# WatchOS5 - how to refresh my complication instantly?

Tags: ios12, apple-watch-complication, watchos-5

I have an apple watch complication and the iPhone app running side by side. I have a button within the app to transmit application context dictionary to the watch. I expect to see the complication title to be refreshed.

I cannot seem to force the "tap button -> see update on the complication" kind of behavior.

**What is the appropriate method to force a complication update?** How can I refresh my apple watch complication instantly?

I do see the title changes, but I think it requires me to tap on the complication to open it's apple watch app first. How can I get the complication to update itself on the Watch home screen?

```
func getCurrentTimelineEntry(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTimelineEntry?) -> Void) {

if complication.family == .graphicRectangular {
  let template = CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicRectangularLargeImage() 
//...configure
  return template
  }
}
```

I see this apple provided code that refreshes the complication. I'm not sure if it is too much, or if calling `extendTimeline` alone is sufficient if I'm generating the complication using the entry above.

```
func refreshComplication() {
      #if os(watchOS)
    let server = CLKComplicationServer.sharedInstance()
    if let complications = server.activeComplications {
        for complication in complications {
            // Call this method sparingly. If your existing complication data is still valid,
            // consider calling the extendTimeline(for:) method instead.
            server.reloadTimeline(for: complication)
        }
    }
    #endif
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32575156/force-reload-watchos-2-complications

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to do this by calling the `refreshComplication()` function from your `didReceiveApplicationContext` block in the file which has your **WCSessionDelegate**.

So if you are receiving the title via an applicationContext message your code would look something along these lines.

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : Any]) {

    if let updatedTitle = applicationContext["updatedTitle"] {
        if let title = updateTitle as? String {
            //Remeber that complicationServer.swift is a seperate process therefore you will need to store the received data somehow.
            UserDefaults.standard.set(title, forKey: "complicationTitle")
            refreshComplication()
        }
    }
}
```

I have a setting in my iOS App that lets the user change their target and using this method refreshed the complication with the new target almost instantly. However, I believe once your complication has used up its cpu budget nothing will happen, but hopefully that is not happening for you. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/clockkit/clkcomplicationserver/1627891-reloadtimeline

Hope that helps, let me know how you get on.
Drew